# Añadir un opciones de un multiple select a un simple select

Tags: javascript, jquery

Estoy usando un select múltiple para llenar un select simple. la idea es, si selecciono un valor y no existe, añadirlo al select simple, si existe no hago nada, pero si desactivo la opción, eliminarla del select simple. ¿Cómo podría hacer eso?

Por ejemplo, selecciono value1 y value2 y los agrego a simple select. Si elimino la selección de value1, debe eliminarse de simple select, pero value2 debe estar ahí.

```js
$(function() {

  $(document).on('change', '#foo', function() {
    var values = $(this).val();

    values.forEach(function(val) {
      $('#bar option').each(function() {
        var v = $(this).val();
        if (values.indexOf(v) === -1) {
          $('#bar').append('<option value="' + val + '">' + val + '</option>');
          return false;
        }
      });
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<select multiple id="foo">
  <option value="value1">value1</option>
  <option value="value2">value2</option>
</select>

<select id="bar">
  <option selected disabled>Add some from multiple</option>
</select>
```

Comment: ¿Con desactivar la opción a qué te refieres? ¿Que deben estar en "azul" en el select #foo para poder estar en el select #bar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

una manera simple y rápida de hacerlo es borrando el contenido del select simple cada vez que se realiza un cambio en el select multiple y añadiendo nuevamente la opción por defecto antes de agregar a través del foreach las opciones seleccionadas, por ejemplo con esta linea:

```
$('#bar').empty().append('<option selected disabled>Add some from multiple</option>');
```

Te dejo el ejemplo funcionando a continuación:

```js
$(function() {

  $(document).on('change', '#foo', function() {
    var values = $(this).val();
    
    $('#bar').empty().append('<option selected disabled>Add some from multiple</option>');

    values.forEach(function(val) {
      $('#bar option').each(function() {
        var v = $(this).val();
        if (values.indexOf(v) === -1) {
          $('#bar').append('<option value="' + val + '">' + val + '</option>');
          return false;
        }
      });
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<select multiple id="foo">
  <option value="value1">value1</option>
  <option value="value2">value2</option>
</select>

<select id="bar">
  <option selected disabled>Add some from multiple</option>
</select>
```